# find all functional dependencies for attribute closure?

Tags: relational-database, rdbms, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, 3nf

It is for a university assignment. I have to list all non-trivial functional dependencies that are applicable, while also trying to ensure that all tables in my schema are 3NF.

I have created an ER Diagram & Relational Schema for my dataset. How can I now find all functional dependencies for attribute closure?

Comment: Right now you are effectively asking for us to rewrite a textbook & you have shown no research or other effort. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show the steps of your work following a textbook/reference with justification & ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re the first place you are stuck. Quote the definitions, theorems, algorithms & heuristics you are relying on. All the steps are also SO faqs. Google with & without 'site:stackoverflow.com'.

Comment: "find all functional dependencies for attribute closure" is not clear.

Comment: Try https://normalizer.db.in.tum.de/